# How to access local PDF file content in Google-Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

I have a local PDF file opened in Google-Chrome tab. Is there any way that I can print its first 4 bytes (of the PDF file) in the Developer-Tools console?

Console and local PDF file

[image]

I already tried different solutions, which suggest me to set up a local HTTP Server using for example Python SimpleHTTPServer. But, I am looking a solution that needs only Chrome builtin features and nothing else.

Comment: What is the full value of `window.location.href`?

Comment: When I disable "Google Docs Offline" extension, it is 'file:///PathToFile.pdf'; and when the extension is enabled, then it is a path starting with "chrome-extention://".

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76409319/how-to-access-local-pdf-file-content-in-google-chrome-console#comment134736174_76409319) The binary data is not accessible using JavaScript APIs at `file:` URLs. It might be possible to access in an extension view, but that's outside the scope of "only Chrome builtin features and nothing else".

Comment: @jsejcksn For the `file:` scheme, running Chrome with "--allow-file-access-from-files" parameter does not help? For the second solution, how can I check if the extension provide a view to the file content?